# Извлечение данных пользователя telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Получаю данные пользователя в следующем виде:

```
User(support=False, phone=None, bot_inline_geo=False, access_hash=6357399922810184, id=447583382, photo=UserProfilePhoto(photo_small=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=257019871, local_id=281399), photo_id=1922355988379314095, dc_id=2, photo_big=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=257019871, local_id=281401)), bot_chat_history=False, bot_info_version=None, bot_inline_placeholder=None, deleted=False, last_name=None, bot_nochats=False, is_self=False, contact=False, mutual_contact=False, min=False, verified=False, scam=False, username='Savonnerie', restricted=False, first_name='Tatiana', lang_code=None, bot=False, status=UserStatusOnline(expires=datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 26, 15, 4, 26, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)), restriction_reason=[])
```

Как извлечь из этих данных параметр datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 26, 15, 4, 26, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(event.message.to_dict()['date'])
```